# Can we take advantage of the type system to make programs more secure?

Tags: java, c++, security, types

This question is inspired from Joel's "Making Wrong Code Look Wrong"

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Sometimes you can use types to enforce semantics on objects beyond their interfaces. For example, the Java interface Serializable does not actually define methods, but the fact that an object implements Serializable says something about how it should be used.

Can we have UnsafeString and SafeString interfaces/subclasses in, say Java, that are used in much of the same way as Joel's Hungarian notation and Java's Serializable so that it doesn't just look bad--it doesn't compile?

Is this feasible in Java/C/C++ or are the type systems too weak or too dynamic?

Also, beyond input sanitization, what other security functions can be implemented in this manner?

Comment: This is also discussed in Podcast 58 ( http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/podcast-58/ )

Comment: it's basically what a type system *is*. Without the type system, any variable could be treated as any other. You'd be able to access out of bounds memory by treating, say, an int as a double. That'd let you get the value of the 4 bytes past the end of the int. Or unsigned integers prevent you from accidentally storing signed values. (although the way they silently convert it isn't ideal)

Comment: Right, but it seems like there's a higher level of properties we can enforce in the type system that has little to do with how we manipulate the data representation. Basically bringing the type system further into the business logic, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type system *already* enforces a huge number of such safety features. That is essentially what it's *for*.

For a very simple example, it prevents you from treating a float as an int. That's one aspect of safety -- it guarantees that the type you're working on are going to behave as expected. It guarantees that only string methods are called on a string. Assembly doesn't have that safeguard, for example.

It's also the job of the type system to ensure that you don't call private functions on a class. That's another safety feature.

Java's type system is too anemic to enforce a lot of interesting constraints effectively, but in many other languages (including C++), the type system can be used to enforce far more wide-ranging rules.

In C++, template metaprogramming gives you a lot of tools for prohibiting "bad" code. For example:

```
class myclass : boost::noncopyable {
 ...
};
```

enforces at compile-time that the class can not be copied. The following will produce compile errors:

```
myclass m;
myclass m2(m); // copy construction isn't allowed
myclass m3;
m3 = m; // assignment also not allowed
```

Likewise, we can ensure at compile-time that a template function only gets called on types which fulfill certain criteria (say, they must be random-access iterators, while bilinear ones aren't allowed, or they must be POD types, or they must not be any kind of integer type (char, short, int, long), but all other types should be legal.

A textbook example of template metaprogramming in C++ implements a library for computing physical units. It allows you to multiply a value of type "meter" with another value of the same type, and automatically determines that the result must be of type "square meter". Or divide a value of type "mile" with a value of type "hour" and get a unit of type "miles per hour".

Again, a safety feature that prevents you from getting your types mixed up and accidentally getting your units mixed up. You'll get a compile error if you compute a value and try to assign it to the wrong type. trying to divide, say, liters by `meters^2` and assigning the result to a value of, say, kilograms, will result in a compile error.

Most of this requires some manual work to set up, certainly, but the language gives you the tools you need to basically build the type-checks you want. Some of this could be better supported directly in the language, but the more creative checks would have to be implemented manually in any case.

Comment: +1 for comment re physical units.  I would recommend every programmer to view the concepts involved there.  It really shows the kind of power and flexibility that I think C++ has over any other language.  (http://learningcppisfun.blogspot.com/2007/01/units-and-dimensions-with-c-templates.html).

Comment: Not "any other". As mentioned in some of the other answers, much of this would have been trivial in Ada, for example

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do such thing.  I don't know about Java, but in C++ it isn't customary and there is no support for this, so you have to do some manual work.  It is customary in some other languages, Ada for example, which have the equivalent of a typedef which introduces a new type which can't be converted implicitly into the orignal one (this new type "inherits" some basic operations from the one it is created, so it stays usefull).

BTW, in general inheritance isn't a good way to introduce the new types, as even if there is no implicit conversion in one way, there is one in the other one.

Comment: What do you mean, it isn't customary in C++? A huge number of metaprogramming tricks are to achieve exactly this kind of safety. Most of boost::type_traits, as well as static assert, uncopyable and a large number of other utilities are designed for this.

Comment: Agreed. So long as your mission is to make it more difficult to forget to sanitize/escape the data prior to storage, manipulation or display, a 'unsafe' type which cannot cast to the 'safe' type is a reasonable solution.

Comment: Depends on what his point is. I disagree that it "isn't customary". But I agree that to enforce a lot of interesting constraints, you have to do some work yourself, or use a library which does it for you. But that doesn't change that it's a very common thing to do in C++. Almost any template class or function performs *some* kind of type check and rejects invalid template arguments at compile-time.

Comment: It isn't customary in C++ to introduce new types which behaves essentially like existing one just to ensure that they aren't used in the wrong context.  It's something I did all the time in Ada.  In a C++ context, Alexandrescu proposed in one paper to make use of volatile this way, for its type checking value and not its language defined semantic (well, some would call that an absence of semantic :-)).

Comment: That's true. But it's still common to use the type system to tailor your types to prevent misuse. But you're right, something like Ada's type system would be an improvement in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a certian amount of this out of the box in Ada. For example, you can make integer types that cannot implcitily interoperate with each other, and Ada enumerations are not compatible with any integer type. You can still convert between them, but you have to *explicitly* do it, which calls attention to what you are doing.

You could do the same with present-day C++, but you'd have to wrap all your integers and enums in classes, which is just way too much work for something that should be simple (or better yet, the default way of doing things).

I understand the next version of C++ is going to fix at least the enumeration issue.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, I suppose you could use `typedef` to create a synonym for a primitive type. Your synonym could imply something about the content of that variable, replacing the function of the apps hungarian notation.

Intellisense will report the synonym you used during declaration, so if you don't like using actual hungarian, it does save you from scrolling about (or using Go To Definition).

Comment: I've done this with integers that represented physical and logical page and block numbers on a flash file system.  The types supported default casts to and from integer, but not to and from each other.  Helped catch a few problems (generally, I used the custom types, but for some loops and such integers were necessary).  The real build used integers, but emulation/test builds used the custom types.  Since the use of different types was to ensure compile-time type-safety, the fact that the emulation/test build was clean meant the real build using integers should be clean as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are thinking of something along the lines of Perl's "tainting" analysis.

In Java, it should be possible to use custom annotations and an annotation processor to implement this.  Not necessarily easy though.

Answer (score -1):

You can't have a UnsafeString subclass of String in Java, since [java.lang.String is final](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

In general, you cannot provide any kind of security on the source level - if you want to protect against evil code, you must do that on the binary level (e.g. Java bytecode). That's why private/protected can't be used as a security mechanism in C++: it is possible to bypass that with pointer manipulations.

Comment: We're not protecting against evil Java code. We're protecting against malicious input (for cross site scripting for example). Using the compiler to weed out 'smells' rather than Joel's Hungarian method is the desire here.

Comment: But good call on the final class part. Though, this would just be a hurdle rather than an impasse.